# Change Region prevents user interaction with the map

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I use MapKit and I use the code below to change the region:

```
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

The problem is while changing the region it prevents user interaction with the map.
How can we cancel or stop the "setRegion" when the user engages with the map?

I expect The map stops changing regions when the user tries to touch it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use mapkit, but I believe you can stop with the following code:

```
extension MKMapView {
    func stopRegionChangeAnimation() {
         self.setRegion(self.region, animated: false)
    }
}
```